# How to Rotate an Image in RML?

Tags: image, rotation, rml

How can I rotate an image in RML? I tried using `rotate degrees="90"` but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to rotate an image with `<rotate degrees="90"/>` put in `<pageGraphics>`.

```
<pageGraphics>
    <rotate degrees="90"/>
    <image x="19cm" y="1cm" height="70.0" >[[ company.footer_img ]]</image>
</pageGraphics>
```